# Customize counter with circled number

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, circles

I'm trying to define new counter `lnum` and display the counter number in circle.

I found `circled` command from here tex.stackexchange but I have a problem.

Here's my test code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\circled}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcounter{lnum}
\renewcommand{\thelnum}{\circled{\arabic{lnum}}}

\begin{document}

\thelnum % fine
\refstepcounter{lnum}\thelnum % error here

\end{document}
```

As you can see from the comment, without `\refstepcounter`, it works fine. However, with `\refstepcounter`, it doesn't work. Here's error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ->\def ;
                              {\tikz@nonactivesemicolon }\def :{\tikz@nonact...
l.11 \refstepcounter{lnum}
                          \thelnum
?
```

Why this doesn't work? And, how can I fix it?

Comment: Do not `\renewcommand{\thelnum}`, it is self-recursive.

Comment: In `\refstepcounter` the `\thelnum` is expanded into a label definition. That is, it must be possible to write `\edef\test{\thelnum}` and that will not work as a Tikz node.

Comment: @Symbol1 I would say you can redefine `\thelnum` as long as it is expandable inside TeX. For example `\renewcommand\thelnum{LNUM: \arabic{lnum}}` should work. I do not see how it is self-recursive.

Comment: @StefanH: Sorry I am not precise, or even misleading --- Anyway: The fact that you have to **RE**newcommand `\thelnum` suggests that this command is already defined and can be used anywhere, anytime. Just because  `\arabic{lnum}` works well does not mean that you are safe. In fact, `\refstepcounter` does invoke `\thelnum` and that is where everything goes wrong.

Comment: @Symbol1 That I agree with completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the command `\thelnum` is expanded inside `\refstepcounter{lnum}`. It is essentally

```
\edef\@currentlabel{\p@lnum\thelnum}
```

where `\p@lnum` is a prefix. If `\thelnum` is a Tikz node that will not be able to expand in this assignment. By testing the definition

```
\edef\test{\tikz \node[draw]{Test};}
```

one gets a similar error as in the question.

To get the printed numbers circled there can be another command writing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\circled}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]
  \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};
}
\newcounter{lnum}
\newcommand{\mylnum}{\circled{\arabic{lnum}}}
\begin{document}
\mylnum % fine
\refstepcounter{lnum}
\mylnum % error here
\end{document}
```

Of course cross-references to the value will not be printed in circles, but that can be done by hand:

```
\refstepcounter{lnum}
\label{circ:test}
[...]
\circled{\ref{circ:test}}
```

Comment: You are right. I simply forgot what `\refstepcounter` does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a ready-made solution from the package `pifont`

```
\begin{dingautolist}{"0AC}
   \item First
   \item Second
\end{dingautolist}
```

Using the starting value `"0B6` you can get white digits on black circles. The digits range from 1 to 10, no higher number are available in the Zapf Dingbats font.

Answer (score 1):

`\refstepcounter` stores the expansion of `\thelnum` in `\@currentlabel` for references. So it is not a good idea if `\thelnum` does complicated things. Either never use `\refstepcounter` with your counter (use `\stepcounter` instead). Or define some other command that adds the circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\circled}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcounter{lnum}
\newcommand{\thecirclnum}{\circled{\arabic{lnum}}}

\begin{document}

\thecirclnum 

\refstepcounter{lnum}\label{test}

\thecirclnum, \ref{test}

\end{document}
```