# How to make Step ❶

Tags: bold

I like to know how to make figures/characters appear like this : `Step ❶:` in Latex. My focus is on `❶` , not `Step`.

Comment: You might find some inspiration here: [A white number inside a black circle.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374932/134144) and here: [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/134144) and here: [Customize counter with circled number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/376102/134144)

Comment: If you were using Xe-/LuaLaTeX you'd only need a font that has the character.